# OpenStack horizon unable to find token

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, openstack-horizon

I am developing OpenStack horizon, and follow quick start at http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/quickstart.html to begin. 
but as I add my backend service url to local_settings.py, and start server. It just throws error like:

> Unauthorized: Could not find token, 99a3682bc1e3a0ca55cb51436a2ff766. (HTTP 401)
>   Unable to retrieve project list.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openstack_auth/user.py", line 308, in authorized_tenants
>       is_federated=self.is_federated)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openstack_auth/utils.py", line 145, in wrapper
>       result = func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openstack_auth/utils.py", line 256, in get_project_list
>       projects = client.tenants.list()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/v2_0/tenants.py", line 123, in list
>       tenant_list = self._list('/tenants%s' % query, 'tenants')
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/base.py", line 113, in _list
>       resp, body = self.client.get(url, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/adapter.py", line 170, in get
>       return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/adapter.py", line 206, in request
>       resp = super(LegacyJsonAdapter, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/adapter.py", line 95, in request
>       return self.session.request(url, method, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/utils.py", line 336, in inner
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/session.py", line 397, in request
>       raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
>   Unauthorized: Could not find token, 99a3682bc1e3a0ca55cb51436a2ff766. (HTTP 401)
>   Unable to retrieve project list.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: I am not sure how I can solve this, because I am struggling for weeks.

Comment: I can access Admin pages, but cannot see the project panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your Horizon can access to the 35357 (keystone admin) port of your Openstack deployment. If Horizon can't access to this port, it will show the same errors.